Is there a way to log AWS Lambda response https handshake status?
I am serving an API using AWS Lambda with ALB in front to it.
@Override
public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent input,
        Context context) {
       ...
       return responseEvent = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent(...);
}

Is there a way to log if my Lambda function has successfully returned the HTTPs response to the client that makes the request? (I want to prove the response is received by the client.)

Your code in the Lambda execution environment does not talk to the client that called the ALB.  It posts a response to the Lambda runtime API, and another layer will respond to the client.  I point this out, because if you want to log any HTTP response, you will need to do it at that level, for instance with the access logs of the ALB
